# steampy login JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, requests, steam, login

Я пытаюсь войти в стим аккаунт используя библиотеку steampy.

```
    print("You not authorized, trying to login into Steam")
    print("Signing in steam account")
    steam_client = SteamClient(api_key=api_key)
    if choose_proxy == '1' or choose_proxy == '2' or choose_proxy == '3':
        steam_client._session.proxies.update({
            "http": f"http://{proxyLog}:{proxyPass}@{proxyIp}",
            "https": f"http://{proxyLog}:{proxyPass}@{proxyIp}"
        })
    steam_client.login(login, password, f'{steam_guard}')
    print('Saving session')
    with open(f'pkl/{pkl_name}', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(steam_client, f)
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Steam_Bot_Development\Lots\Module2_steampy.py", line 784, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Steam_Bot_Development\Lots\Module2_steampy.py", line 777, in main
    steam_client = authorization()
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Steam_Bot_Development\Lots\Module2_steampy.py", line 154, in authorization
    steam_client.login(login, password, f'{steam_guard}')
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\steampy\client.py", line 46, in login
    LoginExecutor(username, password, self.steam_guard['shared_secret'], self._session).login()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\steampy\login.py", line 20, in login
    login_response = self._send_login_request()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\steampy\login.py", line 29, in _send_login_request
    rsa_params = self._fetch_rsa_params()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\steampy\login.py", line 53, in _fetch_rsa_params
    data={'username': self.username}).json()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Буквально вчера этот код работал, но сегодня он уже выдает ошибку.
Можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы исправить ошибку мне пришлось немного отредактировать код steampy, а именно изменить строки в файле steampy/steampy/login.py

```
key_response = self.session.post(SteamUrl.STORE_URL + '/login/getrsakey/', 

return self.session.post(SteamUrl.STORE_URL + '/login/dologin', data=request_data)
```

необходимо поменять `SteamUrl.STORE_URL` на `SteamUrl.COMMUNITY_URL`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" означает, что запрос, который вы отправляете в Steam API не возвращает данные в формате JSON. Это может быть вызвано различными причинами, такими как:

Неверный адрес URL для запроса
Неверный логин или пароль
Неверный API ключ
Ошибка на стороне сервера Steam
Следующим шагом следует проверить каждое из этих условий и убедиться что все данные корректны и доступны. Также можно добавить дополнительные проверки и отладочные сообщения для лучшего понимания происходящего во время выполнения кода. Например, можно проверить значение переменной api_key и убедиться, что она содержит действительный ключ. Также можно проверить состояние соединения с интернетом и проверить доступность сервера Steam. Если проблема не удалось решить с помощью этих шагов, можно посмотреть документацию Steam API или обратиться к сообществу разработчиков Steam за дополнительной помощью.